# Fazer com que o arc4random() não repita o último número

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

Criei um `app` para gerar números aleatórios.

Só que eu queria que ele não repetisse o ultimo número que ele mostrou. Exemplo:

o resultado foi 9

(executo o método que gera o número aleatório de novo)

o resultado foi 9.

Tentei criar uma variável que armazena o valor do último numero `random` e depois comparar em um `if`, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Segundo a documentação da Apple, o arc4random gera números aleatórios de forma uniforme, não devendo gerar números repetidos. Adicione o código onde a função está sendo chamada, assim será mais fácil descobrir qual o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do arc4random() é que ele não gera os numeros com a mesma probabilidade.

Imagino que você deve estar usando o arc4random() desta maneira:

```
arc4random() % number;
```

Por baixo dos panos, o arco4random() não da a mesma probabilidade numérica. Há uma longa discussão sobre isso mas nada como olhar a documentação para entender o essencial:

```
 arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound.
 arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids
 "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.
```

Ou seja, se você usar arc4random_uniform, você tem uma distribuição melhor.

Ja para não repetir o ultimo, por segurança, é melhor você sortear de novo caso o numero anterior seja igual ao sorteado.

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Segue trecho de código que não permite que dezenas sejam repetidas.
No exemplo, serão sorteadas 6 dezenas entre os número 1 e 60.

```
NSMutableArray * arrayNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];

while (YES) {
    int randomNumber = arc4random() % 60;
    BOOL foundNumber = NO;
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayNumbers.count; j++) {
        if ([[arrayNumbers objectAtIndex:j] intValue] == randomNumber) {
            foundNumber = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!foundNumber) {
        [arrayNumbers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomNumber]];
        if (arrayNumbers.count == 6) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", arrayNumbers);
```